# jQuery expand list not expanding when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am stuck on this script. Basically I have unknown amount of categories (20-50) and they are displayed on a sidebar one on top of the other. I want to show 10, then when I push a button, it will expand to show the rest. I have the 10 exposed with the remaining amount closed in a div called cathide. So when I push the button to show, it should expand but it is not.

PHP code generates the list, displays 10 categories, then echos

```
<div class="cathide">
```

then it displays the remaining amount and then echos

```
</div>
```

That is how the reamining is enclosed in a div.

Here are the codes..

PHP

```
if ( $all_categories ) {
$count = 1;

foreach ( $all_categories as $cid => $arr ) {
    $sidebar .= '<a href="index.php?action=sort&cid=' . $cid . '">' . $arr['name'] . ' (' . $arr['count'] . ')</a><br />';

    if ( 10 == $count ) {
        $sidebar .= '<div class="cathide">';
    }

    $count++;
}
$sidebar1 .= '</div>';

} else {
$sidebar = 'There are no categories yet';
}
```

CSS

```
.cathide {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#showAll").click(function () {
$("cathide").slideDown(500);
$(this).hide();
});

$("#hide").click(function () {
$("cathide").slideUp(500, function () {
    $("#showAll").show();
});

});
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="{$theme['borderwidth']}" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" class="tborder">
<tr>
<td class="tab">
Categories
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="trow2">

{$sidebar} // Used to call 10 cats then div class=cathide then remaining cats

{$sidebar1} // Used to call /div
<input type="button" value="Show all" id="showAll" />
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="hide" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The jquery selector needs a '.' to denote a `class`. Anytime you have a problem like this, the first step should be to console the element to make sure it exists, i.e. `console.log($('.someClass'))`

Comment: added the . to the jquery and it still does not work.

Comment: could you set up a fiddle or a jsbin?

Comment: I can probably try. Not sure though. Also if it helps my link is www.codegamer.net and it s the top left sidebar.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need `$(window).ready( function() { });` wrapped around your code. The code is running prior to the DOM being initilized, and thus the selectors come up undefined. Wrap your JavaScript within the window.onload listener on you should be fine. I'll post the answer below.

Comment: I just added it, and still nothing.

Comment: for whatever reason, jQuery is not being loaded. fix that, and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you're missing the window.onload listener so you need to do this:

```
$(window).ready( function() { 

    $("#showAll").click(function () {
       $(".cathide").slideDown(500);
       $(this).hide();
    });

   $("#hide").click(function () {
       $(".cathide").slideUp(500, function () {
    $("#showAll").show();
    });

});
```